# How to whitelist dynamically created scripts in a WebForms project using CSP (Content Security Policy)?

Tags: webforms, content-security-policy, scriptmanager, nonce

Is there a secure way of whitelisting dynamically created scripts in a WebForms project using CSP (Content Security Policy)?

Using `unsafe-inline` like below it works but not recommended.

```
context.Response.Headers.Append("Content-Security-Policy", string.Format("default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"));
```

For any other options such as `nonce-(random)`, we see this CSP error message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash, or a nonce is required to enable
>   inline execution.

[image]

Comment: I had not try this stuff with webforms, but have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461778/add-nonce-attribute-to-auto-generated-webforms-script

Comment: how are you dynamically adding script? one of the RegisterX methods?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'safe-inline' for dynamic scripts, try to use dynamic imports instead? (you can reload such script in code)..

You shouldn't normally have to use 'unsafe-inline', two things that often becomes problematic is the live-reloading in development and setTimeout/setInterval in your code, they can trigger CSP easily. So better to just disable CSP in development to increase your delivery speed. 'unsafe-inline' is to enable execution of dynamically created scripts.

**Update**

To solve this you need to load a custom script using the standard (perhaps with async/defer) `<script src="/myscript.js"></script>` and 'unsafe-inline' requirement goes away. However, your technology choice ("webforms") might limit your options to do that. To test anyway, use a cdn url or a separate server (internal or external) to deliver your script. I have tested this locally with nodejs and it works as expected. The "problem" you have is most likely because that you write code like this (or code is put there):

`<script>function unsafeInline() { ... }</script>`

Modernizr is now v3.6.0 you use v2.8.3 and to make your error go away you can add this to your header:

```
<header>
  <title>CSP Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/;">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

From a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300220/what-is-the-current-best-practice-for-using-content-security-policy-with-moderni):

> If modernizr is injecting all that inline stuff than it seems like your choices are to either (a) add all those hashes, (b) use 'unsafe-inline' (but which basically defeats the whole purpose of CSP…), or (c) don’t use modernizr.

The answer to that question is: remove "inline stuff" from modernizr. You can always use `document.body.style = "background: #000000;";` from an external library to set style (or other) attributes. I tried all "normal" code activities in an imported external script and it doesn't trigger CSP. By normal I also mean assign objects (functions) to the window object and executing them.

**Look for *.createElement("script") or similar, since that will for sure trigger CSP.**

Comment: The link doesn't go anywhere and more information is needed for dynamic imports. Thanks!